# build a data container or point to the existing files in docker?

Tags: docker

currently I am building a ghost blog in docker from the offical ghost docker image -  https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/ghost/

as pointed out, there are two way to link the data.

1. You can also point the image to your existing content on your host:

   docker run --name some-ghost -v /path/to/ghost/blog:/var/lib/ghost ghost

2.Alternatively you can use a data container that has a volume that points to /var/lib/ghost and then reference it:

```
docker run --name some-ghost --volumes-from some-ghost-data ghost
```

previously I used the first way, and I am puzzled why we want to build the data container, is it better than the first way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a Data container is the following (quoting Raman Gupta, link below)

> “this data logically exists within a data-only container and I (probably) don’t care where it physically exists on my host”

To complete this statement I would add : as long as I can access it and backup it. That's just a matter of where it is, and how you want to access it. Thanks to `--volume-from` you can attach to volume from other container so, to give you an example, if you wanted to backup the ghost "data" with a data container, you would have to do something like :

```
docker run -it --rm --volume-from some-ghost my-backup-image > some-ghost-backup.tar.gz
```

The `my-backup-image` would be doing something like : `tar cv /var/lib/ghost | gzip` (I did not try or run it, but that's the basic idea). And you could also use this to manage the data volume and have a common way to access/export (backup) volumes no matter who's using it : https://github.com/cpuguy83/docker-volumes.

Raman Gupta write about it there : https://medium.com/@ramangupta/why-docker-data-containers-are-good-589b3c6c749e

But if you care about where the actual data is, and/or it has to be accessible easily on the host, that's fine too.